# Cpanel Oauth2 Drive sync

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, cpanel

I'm trying to upload files to google drive using oauthdeveloperplayground and cloud console of google it works locally on my machine but when I host it to the cpanel it always send back internal server error message.

I think their might be a domain problem, Can someone please help how to fix that